# mac shell script loop run in background ignored

Tags: macos, shell, loops, scripting, background-process

I have a problem iterating over an array to open multiple instances of a program. When I run the following example I get three instances of fslview:

```
arr=(bold_rs_fabio_precuneus_mask.nii.gz mask.nii.gz bold_rs_fabio.nii.gz)
fslview ${arr[0]} &
fslview ${arr[1]} &
fslview ${arr[2]} &
```

In this example I only get an instance of fslview with the first file loaded:

```
arr=(bold_rs_fabio_precuneus_mask.nii.gz mask.nii.gz 
bold_rs_fabio.nii.gz)
for f in $arr
do
    fslview $f &
done
```

What am I missing in the second example?

Thanks in advance
Martin

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should start a new shell within the loop:

```
arr=(bold_rs_fabio_precuneus_mask.nii.gz mask.nii.gz bold_rs_fabio.nii.gz)
for f in $arr
do
  (fslview $f & )
done
```

Or try to build a command line to actually run the processes in parallel

```
arr=(bold_rs_fabio_precuneus_mask.nii.gz mask.nii.gz bold_rs_fabio.nii.gz)
cmd=""
for f in $arr
do
  cmd="$cmd fslview $f &"
done
#then let it run
$cmd
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I am intrigued as to why that makes a difference - would you care to explain please?

Comment: I guess `&` applies to a command line in a given shell... I'm not completely sure how it works for OSX. Just trying to help.

Comment: hi Mark, thanks for your ideas. Did not make a change though. I am using this script in a mac automator app.  Maybe someone knows a workaround?

Comment: @gimba, you should edit your question, then, for more accuracy or close it and open a new one.